# Changing border of the main form of the WinForm application

Tags: .net, winforms, skinning, winforms-interop, wndproc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resize WinForm, with no border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575216/resize-winform-with-no-border)

I want my WinForm application to NOT have any border. **But still I want to be able to move the application using mouse, resize the application.**

How can I achieve this?

I have gone through some blogs and questions on the Stackoverflow which talk about applying various themes to the WinForm by overriding `WndProc` method of the Windows `Form` class. E.g. http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/

Note that I don't want to apply various skins or themes. I just want to make border disappear (or make thickness of the border as small as possible, as if there is just thin border around the main client area of the form). Please note that I do NOT want the title bar at all.

I am using .NET 4.0.

Comment: @Hans Passant : The solution you proposed there is good. Can you please guide me on how a border can be made thinner (without hiding it completely) and that too with some different color?

Comment: Hmm, you asked for NOT in capital letters.  You can fake any kind of border you want in a borderless form by just drawing a rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link from CodeProject on [moving a form without a titlebar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11114/Move-window-form-without-Titlebar-in-C).
Now, ***I know*** that in the image it shows a titlebar. But if you download the code, remove the form's `Text` and set the `ControlBox` to false; You get a form which is moveable and without a titlebar.

I should note that it still has a *thin* border (just like you mentioned you want)

**Update:** 
After viewing [@HansPassant's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575452/1379664) (which is also a very good solution) - Setting the `FormBorderStyle` property to `None` in the CodeProject code completely removes the border and still makes the form moveable:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.Text = String.Empty;
    this.ControlBox = false;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; 
    ....
```