# VSTUDIO2012 How to make a "borderstyle = none" form MOVEABLE

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, forms, visual-studio-2012

I'm learnning vstudio 2012, I'm trying to make moveable a form with "borderstyle = none" but i can't.

All the info that i found in Google talks about vb4 5 & 6 about this problem, versions too earlier for me and i cannot use they (I don't know how to).

my declaraments is very simple, i only need to make the window moveable by clicking on the app (anywhere on the form):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label2.Text = "X: " & MousePosition.X
        Label3.Text = "Y: " & MousePosition.Y

    End Sub

    Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, _
      ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar >= ChrW(3) Then
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(Label2.Text & " " & Label3.Text)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Any help please? thankyou for read

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize WinForm, with no border?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575216/resize-winform-with-no-border)

Comment: i think not, that question is about C# !

Comment: Neither Windows nor .NET nor Winforms care what language you use.  Use an online C#-to-VB.NET converter if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this, thanks.

```
Private ArrastrarForm As Boolean
Private PosicionMouseHeader As Point
Private tmpPoint As Point


Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        ArrastrarForm = True
        PosicionMouseHeader = e.Location
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
    If ArrastrarForm Then
        tmpPoint = Me.Location + e.Location - PosicionMouseHeader
        Me.Location = tmpPoint
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        ArrastrarForm = False
    End If
End Sub
```

bye!