# How to create a borderless window but resizeable like visual studio in win32 app?

Tags: wpf, windows, winforms

How to create a borderless but resizable window like visual studio's win32 app?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOVgP.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Borderless and Resizable Form (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199437/borderless-and-resizable-form-c)

Comment: Visual Studio's window is not borderless...

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for has already been coded with Mahapps.Metro. http://mahapps.com/

The project is open source so if you don't want it all could just grab what you need. It's also available as a Nuget package.