# Prevent a borderless form from moving/resizing when maximized

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on the UI for an application using Windows Form. I made a resizable borderless form after consulting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199437/borderless-and-resizable-form-c) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748446/custom-resize-handle-in-border-less-form-c-sharp/19670447#19670447) as well.

But now, I have an issue in the maximized state, that is, if I move the mouse to the edge, I can still resize the form. How do I make the form Freeze in the maximized state to prevent this resizing?

Code to make form Borderless

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE = 10;

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x0084/*NCHITTEST*/ :
                base.WndProc(ref m);

                if ((int)m.Result == 0x01/*HTCLIENT*/)
                {
                    Point screenPoint = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
                    Point clientPoint = this.PointToClient(screenPoint);
                    if (clientPoint.Y <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                    {
                        if (clientPoint.X <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)13/*HTTOPLEFT*/ ;
                        else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)12/*HTTOP*/ ;
                        else
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)14/*HTTOPRIGHT*/ ;
                    }
                    else if (clientPoint.Y <= (Size.Height - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                    {
                        if (clientPoint.X <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)10/*HTLEFT*/ ;
                        else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)2/*HTCAPTION*/ ;
                        else
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)11/*HTRIGHT*/ ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (clientPoint.X <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)16/*HTBOTTOMLEFT*/ ;
                        else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)15/*HTBOTTOM*/ ;
                        else
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)17/*HTBOTTOMRIGHT*/ ;
                    }
                }
                return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= 0x20000; // <--- use 0x20000
            cp.ClassStyle |= 0x08; 
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

Code to quit,maximize/restore,minimize

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.WindowState==FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            this.button2.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Restore_Down));
            this.MaximizedBounds = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle).WorkingArea;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        }
        else if(this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.button2.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Maximize));
        }
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
```

Comment: I [strongly suggest](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/) you post your current code into the question because we don't know what parts you used (or didn't use) from the two linked questions.

Comment: added code as suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your WndProc method is intercepting the WM_NCHITTEST (client window hit test) message and is setting the result (e.g. mouse is hitting an edge) based on the position of the mouse. These results are then used to trigger other functionality.

If you don't want this functionality to happen when your window is in a maximised state, just bypass it.

Wrap the code (inside WndProc) in something like...

```
if (this.WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized)
{
    // existing code
}
```