# How is resize handled by DWM? C#

Tags: c#, resize, flicker, aero, dwm

I have tried to create a custom border less form for my application. I decided that it had to be resizable, so I put 8 panels on its sides (4 corners, 4 sides actually) and created code which will resize my form when called. Like, for example:

```
    private void E_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Active = true;
    }
    private void East_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Active)
        {
            this.Size = new Size(this.Width + e.Location.X, this.Height);
            this.Refresh();

        }
    }
    private void E_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Active = false;
    }
```

Unfortunately, the resizing is slow, overloads the CPU and performs visual glitches even with double buffering for the form turned on. I have quite a bit of controls on my form. But what I have noticed is the fact that when I switch to a standard border (like `Sizable`), and DWM handles the window chrome, resizing is perfect. No glitches, stuttering and flicker. So I came to wonder, how does Windows manage to do? Is there a way to simulate what it is doing via the 8 panels? I hate when it flickers and it halts my project for no reason. The fact is that I worked all day long to mimic the Visual Studio 2013 window chrome and nearly suceeded, there is just this annoying problem... Can you help, please?

Thanks.

Comment: It uses this.Invalidate(), not this.Refresh().  Use [WM_NCHITTEST](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2575452/17034) instead of panels.

Comment: How, can you elaborate a bit? I am new to this, I do not really know how to do it...? Thanks.

Comment: You got copy/paste code, if you can't get that going then you ought to be focusing on something else.  Then again, one minute isn't exactly enough to even try it.  Try it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, finally. I failed for me because of my custom CreateParams... anyway, any idea on how to set a form padding's color?