# Why i can't change the position of the Form when I set FormBorderStyle None in C# WinForm application

Tags: c#, winforms

I built a small c# application, that have `FormBorderStyle` set to `None`, but when execute it, I can't move the Form. But if I set the `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedSingle` or other value, I can move the form with mouse.

Comment: Its not fixed, there just isn't any handle left to move it, you need to either override the mouse handler or have the border there. Edit: I haven't tried this but you can probably confirm this by pressing Windows Key and Right which should resize/move it to the side of your screen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575216/resize-winform-with-no-border/2575452#2575452