# How would I add a resize border like WPF's WindowStyle.None in Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, forms, winforms

I am creating an application with a custom borderless form in `Visual Basic` using `Windows Forms`. I am hoping to have a simple resize border and drop shadow as seen when setting a Window's `WindowStyle` property to `None` in `WPF.` You are left with a 1px border which you can use to resize the form, see below:

[image: A WPF Window set to WindowStyle.None and being resized with the cursor.]

When you set up a borderless form in `Windows Forms` using `FormBorderStyle.None`, you don't get the drop shadow or resize border. How would I go about getting these both in a `Windows Form` Form?

I am aware that I could do this using things like `Guna.UI` framework, but I do not have the budget for this, and I am looking to try and do this myself. Any help will be greatly appreciated! If anyone has any further question on what I am asking, please let me know.

Thanks, Will.

Comment: [How to move and resize a form without a border?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2575216/10216583)

Comment: This does work, however it is quite clunky and takes quite a bit of setup, I will look into incorperating it into my project, thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Welcome. Also you can find many almost complete sets published for free including the source codes to tweak/improve them as you wish.  [This](https://github.com/q8soft/WinFrmSkins.xVisual) and [this](https://github.com/q8soft/WinFrmSkins.NYX) for example. Good luck.